# Playing Audio without delay in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, audio, audio-streaming

I know blackberry audio player has internal buffer which has to be filled before it starts playing. This causes about 2 seconds delay before the player starts. 
Can i eliminate the delay and start playing audio as soon as possible.

Is there any way to reduce the internal buffer size.

If yes can any one tell me how to do it....

I am using blackberry os version 5.

Thanks and regards

Uttam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the buffer size cannot be eliminated. This buffer is introduced somewhere in mid os 5 version. In previous versions you only have initial buffer you have to fill.

(Answer of the first related topic, try to use the search function next time;))

Comment: Yes,a message in form of a small gif or text can be used to make it less of a wait. It is blackberry specific but I know that Bada has something similiar, but thats another story. Hope this helps. Good luck